# Louis Wu and Bey Shaeffer

Tags: known-space

In Ringworld Engineers, Louis wonders about the Long Shot's pilot. Why doesn't he know it was his own stepfather?

Comment: This is actually retconned in the *<Thing> of Worlds* books. The short-short version is the Wu is unclear on his family history (and in any case Beowolf is not his genetic grandfather, Carlos Wu is). Don't have mine handy to write a real answer.